# Shall I delete the pointer manually in v8::External?

Tags: c++, v8

```
Local<ObjectTemplate> tpl = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
tpl->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
Local<Object> ret = tpl->NewInstance();
TestExternal* ex = new TestExternal();
ret->SetInternalField(0, External::New(isolate, ex));
```

Shall I delete the `ex` pointer manually when `ret` is no longer in use?

Where's the evidence source code shows that I should or shouldn't do that?

Comment: Why did you `new` it in the first place?

Comment: @juanchopanza The `TestExternal` is a my own class, not a class of v8. I wrapped it with `v8::External` and let it be an internal field of `ret`.

Comment: Whatever but why did you `new` it in the first place?

Comment: @juanchopanza so if I don't `new` it, what shall I do? I `new` it according to Embedder's Guide of V8.

Comment: No idea, bu the documentation should tell you what to do. Does it tell you to pass a newed pointer? If so, does it say who should delete it?

Comment: @juanchopanza the documentation doesn't mention about it. So I am confused.

Comment: If it doesn't say anything, chances are `External::New()` doesn't require the thing to be newed and it is up to the caller to clean up. This would mean that you don't need to `new` the object.

Comment: some similar code shows it could be `new`ed. but nowhere shows that whether it should be deleted manually.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/opensource/os-cn-v8engine/#listing5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, C++ requires manual memory management: if you manually create an object with `new`, then you also have to manually `delete` it when it is no longer needed. If you don't delete it, then your program will work, but it will leak memory. If you delete it too early (while other objects still have pointers to it), then that's called a "use-after-free" bug, which typically causes crashes and can be exploited.

There is nothing specific to V8 about this. The `v8::External` cannot automatically delete your objects because it does not know how your application works -- only *you* know when the objects can safely be deleted, and how they must be deleted (a `void*` doesn't know about destructors).

V8's `Persistent` handles can be marked "weak" and invoke a callback when V8's GC is about to free the object they're referring to. However, the documentation in v8.h strongly recommends not to rely on this:

> NOTE: There is no guarantee as to *when* or even *if* the callback is
>     invoked. The invocation is performed solely on a best effort basis.
>     As always, GC-based finalization should *not* be relied upon for any
>     critical form of resource management!

So you should keep track of all your objects on the C++ side and have some plan B for freeing them.

Comment: Thanks, I've got this answer from Node.js' source code too. Node.js' ObjectWrap uses the `Persistent::SetWeak` way to trace the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `v8::External` to delete an object of type `TestExternal` for you, then you should somehow let it know that it is managing an object of `TestExternal`.

Since this is usually done via class template and `v8::External` is not declared as a template, my guess is that it probably won't call `delete` for you and you need to delete the pointer manually.